# Any sample / possible redirect uri(s) for OAuth api based applications?

Tags: mobile, oauth

I want to develop an desktop application which uses a webservice.
for this webservice provides 'oauth api(s)'
for oauth api usage in my application, I need to register my application , where it asks for 
redirect uri ie., some domain name so that it will "redirect after OAuth authorization to URLs from this domain only and also not to prepend http or https or any URL scheme.

Are there any free/ possible names I can make use of OR any alternative solutions for this ? In Future, will there be any restrictions for the domain names I use , if more no.of users use my app?

Answer (score 0):

well this might not be what you were asking for, but have you look into google API ? it provides many resources related to what you are trying to do.